# How to turn installer back into Java Code; such as when using netbean?

Tags: java, netbeans, installation, revert

I pretty much get the idea that when we *export / created the installer after reading to the code.*

The person who had the **installer** and **the java class; also the DB**, will **not be able to edit or view the java code** aside **from seeing tons of .class file.**

~~~~~~

Due to pressure, and me being unable to be 100% sure if I can convert it back to java code; I wonder if any expert can give me a confirmation on my understanding and suggestion?

***My intention is to perform unit testing, edit/ view code.***

I really appreciate any help provided.

Thank you so much.

Comment: google for *java decompiler*

Comment: :o 

Thank you for your suggestion :) 
I see, so i can copy the code and recreate the java file. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using java ***decompiler*** appear to be able to help on this as suggested by @Scary Wombat.